# Integrate SimplesamlPHP with Java application

Tags: java, simplesamlphp

I want to use simplesamlphp for java application for running unit tests and karate tests. So, I did simplesamlphp setup locally and able to test simplesamlphp installation successfully. 
Now how can I integrate this simplesamlphp setup with my application and run tests.

Thanks in advance.

I followed following instructions to setup simplesamlphp

https://github.com/kristophjunge/docker-test-saml-idp

and

https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp